# t-test in R by specific factors

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution, hypothesis-test

I have a data set with a few variables:

X is a numeric variable, Y and Z are factor variables containing only 2 factors (Y=1,2   Z=3,4)

```
             x y z
1  -0.59131983 1 3
2   1.51800178 1 3
3   0.03079412 1 3
4  -0.43881764 1 3
5  -1.44914000 1 3
6  -1.33483914 1 4
7   0.25612595 1 4
8   0.12606742 1 4
9   0.44735965 1 4
10  1.83294817 1 4
11 -0.59131983 2 3
12  1.51800178 2 3
13  0.03079412 2 3
14 -0.43881764 2 3
15 -1.44914000 2 3
16 -1.33483914 2 4
17  0.25612595 2 4
18  0.12606742 2 4
19  0.44735965 2 4
20  1.83294817 2 4
```

A t-test is easy to perform if my factor variable is Y (t.test(X~Y)). but i am not sure how to do a t-test which would compare for example only the X values for Y==2, between Z (3 and 4)?

I am not sure if I expressed myself correct, so it might be easier to see it in the table. So, I would like to do a t test for X, where the factor variable is Z and Y==2. how could i do this?
in STATA it is easy:
ttest var1 if var3==3, by(var2)

but i dont get it in R :(

```
         x     y  z
11 -0.59131983 2 3
12  1.51800178 2 3
13  0.03079412 2 3
14 -0.43881764 2 3
15 -1.44914000 2 3
16 -1.33483914 2 4
17  0.25612595 2 4
18  0.12606742 2 4
19  0.44735965 2 4
20  1.83294817 2 4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the `t.test` documentation in R you will see that for one-sample t.tests you shouldn't use the formula interface of the function (type `?t.test`):

> The formula interface is only applicable for the 2-sample tests.

So, in your case you need to create a subset of your data.frame according to the conditions you specified like this:

```
df2 <- df[df$y==2 & df$z %in% c(3,4), ]

> df2
             x y z
11 -0.59131983 2 3
12  1.51800178 2 3
13  0.03079412 2 3
14 -0.43881764 2 3
15 -1.44914000 2 3
16 -1.33483914 2 4
17  0.25612595 2 4
18  0.12606742 2 4
19  0.44735965 2 4
20  1.83294817 2 4
```

And then run the one-sample `t.test` using the following syntax:

```
> t.test(x=df2$x)

    One Sample t-test

data:  df2$x
t = 0.1171, df = 9, p-value = 0.9094
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.7275964  0.8070325
sample estimates:
 mean of x 
0.03971805
```